# Issues with catching exceptions in a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have written the following class:

```
class AsyncPillow:
    def __init__(self, FUNC: Callable, ARGS: tuple, POOL: ThreadPoolExecutor = None):
        self.FUNC = FUNC
        self.ARGS = ARGS
        self.POOL = POOL if POOL else ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_name_prefix = 'thread', initializer = None, initargs = None)

    def Exceptions(self):
        print('callback was called!')
        if e := self._future.exception():
            print(e)

    async def Call(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            self._future: asyncio.Future = loop.run_in_executor(self.POOL, self.FUNC, *self.ARGS)
            await self._future

            self._future.add_done_callback(self.Exceptions)
        except Exception as e: 
            print(e)


    @property
    def result(self):
        return self._result if self._result else None
```

The function (self.FUNC) is the following:

```
def test():
 print(1/0)
```

I have been struggling with trying to catch errors for threads that I have called, the code does not continue after awaiting self._future neither do any exceptions get catched, nor does Exceptions run.

What would I have to change to be able to catch exceptions using add_done_callback and be able to return the future's result after its done.

EDIT:
Additionally,

```
        try:
            self._future: asyncio.Future = loop.run_in_executor(self.POOL, self.FUNC, *self.ARGS)
            await self._future

            self._future.add_done_callback(self.Exceptions)
        except: 
            print('hello')
```

DOES output 'hello'. I am not able to explain this behaviour and would appreciate any assistance!

awaiting self._future causes the except to get triggered.

Comment: can't replicate it [godbolt run](https://godbolt.org/z/Wjr9G3rxY)

Comment: @AhmedAEK that is very odd. I found out partially what the cause is though, awaiting self._future results in a asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError.. not sure what the root cause of this is though, as the thread is still running (I have tested this by adding a time.sleep() to test.

EDIT: The main event loop is also still running, I have checked this with loop.is_running() after catching CancelledError

Comment: @AhmedAEK what if you wrap it in an asyncio task?: https://godbolt.org/z/TGh38bz19

Answer (score 0):

Found out my issue.. its very silly..

Call is part of a task that i create with loop.create_task.

I however, never **awaited** loop.create_task, causing the task to get cancelled (I suppose(?)) while the Future is active.